# c# Websocket not sending message before closing the connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket

I have an application where I use `System.Net.Websockets.WebSocket` class to send information over a websocket. Everything works well except for a nasty detail. When an error happens I want the server to send an error message through the websocket and then close the connection. It works like this:

```
private async Task CloseOnError(ErrorMessage error, WebSocket socket)
        {
            await SendErrorMessage(error, socket);
            await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.InvalidMessageType, "ClosedOnError", CancellationToken.None);
            return;
        }

        private async Task SendErrorMessage(ErrorMessage error, WebSocket socket)
        {
            await SendMessageAsync(socket, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error));
            return;
        }

private async Task SendMessageAsync(WebSocket socket, string message)
        {
            if (socket == null || socket.State != WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                return;
            }

            await socket.SendAsync(
                buffer: new ArraySegment<byte>(
                    array: Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message),
                    offset: 0,
                    count: message.Length),
                messageType: WebSocketMessageType.Text,
                endOfMessage: true,
                cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

I call `CloseOnError` passing a custom `ErrorMessage` object and the instance of `WebSocket` I am using. `SendErrorMessage` sends the error serialized to json through the websocket, and then I close the websocket using `socket.CloseAsync`.

When the program runs the websocket client never receives the error message. However if I debug the program and run it step by step, the error message is received by the client. It seems like if the closing is happening so fast after the sending, that the data is not flushed to the underlying socket. In fact, if a put a `Thread.sleep(1000)` after `await SendErrorMessage`, the client does receive the data.

I've searched for ways to flush the buffer of the socket before closing, but I have not found any ([WebSocket class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket?view=netcore-2.1) does not seem to allow access to the underlying socket).

How can I make the error message make it to the wire without using that nasty `Thread.sleep()`?

Comment: Looks like a race condition to me. You could check WebSocketCloseStatus (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocketclosestatus?view=netcore-2.1)  and open a new one if necessary? But even thats not bulletproof (it might close between the check and the send call.

Comment: Finally I realized the problem was not on the server side, but on the client one. Trying with another websocket client (wscat) it worked perfectly.